# How do I find which template is being referenced using smarty syntax?

Tags: html, css, smarty

I currently have the following code that is written in with Smarty templates, and I'm a little unsure how to deal with the syntax:

```
    <div class="member_actions">{component ProfileActions profile_id=$actorId}</div>       
    {if $owner_mode && $componentManage}
        {component $profile_component_select}
    {/if}
```

I understand that there is a div being created here, and that within that div they've added a component called "profileActions"; however, i do have a file folder called "components" and there is a style sheet called "Profile Actions", but it's empty. I'm a little unsure where this is coming from exactly. I don't know how to make edits to this stylesheet. could someone please tell me what the code is saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here:

```
{component ...}
```

`component` is the custom [Smarty Function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl). You can find it in Smarty plug-in directory or in a file that keeps all functions (if there is one) for your project.

In case you want to find *the ends*, just search through your whole web-site directory for the following content:

```
smarty_function_component
```

It must be found anyway, because it's the only way you can register custom *Smarty function*.

#### EDIT 1:

If the plug-in is registered dynamically using [`registerPlugin`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) method:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","component", ...)
```

then you would have to search for the following instead:

```
registerPlugin("function","component"
```

or

```
registerPlugin(" function ", " component "
```